# how do I display which template is used in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I get Wordpress to show which template file is being processed to generate a page of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current page template, you should use:

```
get_page_template();
```

See more here: [get_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template)

To get the current WordPress theme template, you should use [wp_get_theme()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) function.

```
$current_theme = wp_get_theme();
echo $my_theme->Name;
```